# Pipe the output of “ls -G1” to “sed” while retaining output colors in macOS

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, sed, ls

When using the terminal in macOS I created an alias in `~/.bash_profile` that lets me list folders and files in one column and with color using the `-G1` option like this:

```
something = "ls -G1"
```

This work great, but then I would like to add extra spaces (indentation) so that an output like this:

```
Folder 1
Folfer 2
Folder 3
```

becomes:

```
<space>Folder 1
<space>Folder 2
<space>Folder 3
```

This would be possible if I add `sed 's/^/   /'` and write:

```
something = "ls -G1 | sed 's/^/   /'"
```

But if I add `sed`, whatever I do, I lose output color.

Is there a way to add indentation to `ls` output and preserve the original output colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in this answer on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497442/30848), you need to prefix that command with `CLICOLOR_FORCE=1` like this:

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -G1 | sed 's/^/   /'
```

So your alias them becomes:

```
something = "CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -G1 | sed 's/^/   /'"
```

The problem with your `ls` command is `-G` is the equivalent of `CLICOLOR` which is described on [this `ls` environment variable documentation page as follows](https://ss64.com/osx/ls-env.html); bold emphasis is mine:

> Use ANSI color sequences to distinguish file types.  See LSCOLORS below.
>
> In addition to the file types mentioned in the -F option some extra attributes (setuid bit set, etc.) are also displayed. The colorization is dependent on a terminal type with the proper termcap(5) capabilities.
>
> The default ''cons25'' console has the proper capabilities, but to display the colors in an xterm(1), for example, the TERM variable must be set to ''xterm-color''.  Other terminal types might require similar adjustments.
>
> **Colorization is silently disabled if the output isn't directed to a terminal unless the CLICOLOR_FORCE variable is defined.**

Note how your command is piping `ls` output to `sed`. Since that is not direct output to the terminal, that option is silently disabled.

Thus you need to use `CLICOLOR_FORCE` which is described on the same [`ls` environment variable page](https://ss64.com/osx/ls-env.html) as follows:

> Color sequences are normally disabled if the output isn't directed to a terminal. This can be overridden by setting this flag. The TERM variable still needs to reference a color capable terminal however otherwise it is not possible to determine which color sequences to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works... I thought -G was the same of CLICOLOR_FORCE=1.

Comment: @Giuseppe You’re welcome! I edited my answer to explain how you need to use `CLICOLOR_FORCE` with `ls` if the output is piped to another command and not directly going to the Terminal.

Comment: Very easy to understand... now :)  Just one more think: if I add CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 and preserve -G everything works very well. If I remove -G the output is without colors, even if CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 is presented.

Comment: @Giuseppe Good catch. I just edited my answer to leave the `-G` in the `ls -G1` command.